# No Windows popping up while using pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I have been using pycharm in my mac but while importing pygame, there is no window popping up. I have copied some codes from google about pygames but it is also not working. I think there might some settings problem in mac os because in my pc the code is working perfectly. Another information is that no error is showing, which means no problem with code or interpreter.

Comment: How are you executing the script? Are you double-clicking on the file, or are you running something like `python script.py`? If not the latter of the two, please run it that way, and check if the programs crashes or not.

Comment: I am just running a simple pygame related code in pycharm and simply pressing the run button and there is no windows coming up, but in my dock section a little python launcher keeps jumping but showing nothing

Comment: Okay, I'll ask it in another way: Does the script work **outside** of pycharm? As in, when you launch the code in a shell, does the code execute correctly? If it does, the problem is in pycharm, if not, the problem is in the code and you have narrowed the problem down to a single variable.

Comment: It did worked with jupiter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, and other people, Python 3.8 doesn't work with PyGame for some reason. Try using Python 3.7.

Comment: But the same code works in windows, I checked it a while ago and there is python 3.8 installed

Comment: As a token of appreciation, you can accept the answer. So if other people have the same problem, they will know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using PyCharm...

I found, as a workaround, on Apple,
if your "Force Quit" the running Python in the Dock,
and then try to run it again you get:

[image: Screen Shot after "Force Quit" and rerun in PyCharm]

Whichever one your choose, it then continues and displays the window.

[image: After you click either choice]